# How to repair string offset?

Tags: php

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 4 in 67

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($name); $i++)
if($name[$i] == $name[($i+1)] && $name[$i] == $name[($i+2)])
```

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: -1 in 73

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($name); $i++)
if($name[$i-1] == ' ' && $name[$i+1] == ' ')
```

These are the functions, which check the corectness of name.
First one is blocking the name with 3 the same letters one by one, for example "Maaark".
And the second one is for blocking format like tis "M a a r k".

Please help me fix this :D

Comment: Dude... you're doing `$i=0;` then checking `if($name[$i-1]`. This is checking the position `-1` of the string, which will never exist since the first string position will always be 0.

Comment: Just look at your indexes, in both `for` loops you allow them to address **non existant occurances** Just fix your algorithms

Comment: yes it give an error because if your string length is 4 and in 2 time enter into your loop $name[($i+2)] give error. It would not initialized. same like for -1 index is not exist in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your two for loops like follows

```
      for($i = 0; $i < (strlen($name)-2); $i++){
          if($name[$i] == $name[($i+1)] && $name[$i] == $name[($i+2)]){
             echo "first";
          }
       }
```

and

```
    for($i = 1; $i < (strlen($name)-1); $i++){
       if($name[$i-1] == ' ' && $name[$i+1] == ' '){  
          echo "second";
       }
    }
```

Comment: First works ideally, but it shows communicate about 3 same letters one by one every time, even if the error should be with the spaces between letters. I can show you the full code if you want

Comment: I didn't get you completely.. so you're saying that the problem is with the second loop now?